# Why are the vowels in "sense", "nonsense" and "nonsensical" pronounced differently?

Tags: pronunciation, british-english, vowels

I'm a bit confused by these words. Since "nonsense" derives from "sense" but the vowel in "sense" is /ɛ/ and it reduces to /ə/ in "nonsense". BUT "nonsensical" derives from "nonsense" and the vowel in it is the same as "sense". Please explain.

Comment: It doesn't always reduce in *nonsense,* for example in most of the US, if not all.

Comment: I've added 'British English' tag to your question because most (if not all) Americans don't have a schwa in 'nonsense'.

Comment: I think that in AmE, "nonsince" is more common than "nonsunce".

Answer (score 6):

This is because of weird stress patterns of English. The stress patterns of English are very complex.

*Sense* is a monosyllabic (one-syllable) word and is stressed, so the vowel is pronounced /ɛ/ and does not get reduced to a weak vowel (schwa).

However, when you prepend the prefix *non* to *sense*, the primary stress moves from the second syllable of 'nonsense (i.e. 'sense') to the first syllable 'non' because it's a disyllabic noun and disyllabic nouns are almost always stressed on the first syllable. Therefore, the vowel in the second syllable gets reduced to a schwa /ə/ (vowels in unstressed syllables often get reduced to schwa). Therefore, 'nonsense' is pronounced ['nɒns**ə**ns].*

On the other hand, 'nonsensical' is pronounced [nɒn's**ɛ**nsɪkl̩]. The vowel in the second syllable doesn't get reduced to /ə/ because it is stressed now. Like most adjectives that end with *-ical*, 'nonsensical' is stressed on the antepenult (third-last syllable). Therefore, the vowel in its second syllable doesn't get reduced to /ə/.

(*This case is more complicated but I'm not going to explain it further because it will confuse you.)

Comment: Good answer.  Usually when we add a non- prefix to a monosyllable, though, the stress is on the second syllable.  I think the key thing about "nonsense" is that the "non-" is no longer perceived as a prefix.  "Nonsense" has become a full word in its own right (and not merely the opposite of "sense") and is never hyphenated.  (Still, in AmE, the "e" is sometimes fully pronounced: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/nonsense ).

Comment: @rjpond: OR because 'nonsense' is a noun and like most other disyllabic nouns, it's stressed on the first syllable. :) There's more to this than meets the eye.

Comment: Is this a BrE thing? All three seem to have the same vowel in AmE.

Comment: @StephenS Seems to be. We Brits certainly put a schwa in **nonsense**.